# Preferred notation for a set that evolves over time

Tags: notation

Say I want a set $\mathcal{S}$ to represent the people present in a room at any given time. Person $k$ enters the room at time $t_{\mathrm{in},k}$ and exits at time $t_{\mathrm{out},k}$. To give a simple definition, I assume that people who have left the room do not re-enter.

I want to write something like:

$$
\mathcal{S} \text{ at time $t$}= \left\{k: t_{\mathrm{in},k}\leq t\leq t_{\mathrm{out},k} \right\}
$$

Somehow it feels strange to write $\mathcal{S}(t)$ on the LHS because it implies a function, and I am used to functions mapping onto an element of a set, not onto a set. Of course, we can consider the set of all possible combinations of people in the room at time $t$, of which $\mathcal{S}$ is an element, but this feels clunky. Would $\mathcal{S}_t$ or something else be preferable?

Comment: How about subscript, $S_t$

Comment: What is wrong with having a set-valued function?  e.g. a function $\mathcal{S} : [0, \infty) \to \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (here, each person corresponds to a natural number; the set of people in the room is a set of natural numbers, i.e. an element of the powerset of the natural numbers).  Of course, there is nothing wrong with the subscript, either.